# Flex 4.6 Right use of packages in Flex Mobile

Tags: sqlite, mobile, flash-builder, package

Just started with Flex Mobile, i have created a package:

```
package valueObjects
{
    import flash.data.SQLConnection;
    import flash.data.SQLStatement;
    import flash.filesystem.File;

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.collections.ListCollectionView;

    public class Dbsql
    {
        public var connection:SQLConnection;
        public var result:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        public var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;
        public var brand:String;

        public function Dbsql()
        {
        }

        public function listBrands():Array
        {
            var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;
            sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
            sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/db.sqlite"));
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = 
                "SELECT HoofdGroep FROM products " +
                "GROUP BY HoofdGroep " +
                "ORDER BY HoofdGroep ASC ";
            stmt.execute();
            var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
            return result;          
        }

        public function listGroups(brand:String):Array
        {
            var sqlConnection:SQLConnection;
            sqlConnection = new SQLConnection();
            sqlConnection.open(File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("assets/db.sqlite"));
            var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
            stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
            stmt.text = 
                "SELECT HoofdGroep, ArtikelSubGroep FROM products  " +
                "WHERE HoofdGroep = '" + brand + "' " +
                "GROUP BY ArtikelSubGroep " +
                "ORDER BY ArtikelSubGroep ASC ";
            stmt.execute();
            var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
            return result;          
        }
    }
}
```

A Home view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Aurum Sales" initialize="init()"> <!--initialize="init()"-->

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import valueObjects.Dbsql;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            protected function init():void
            {
                var getClass:Dbsql = new Dbsql();
                list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(getClass.listBrands());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="list" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" labelField="HoofdGroep" change="navigator.pushView(GroupView, list.selectedItem)"> 
    </s:List>

</s:View>
```

And a second view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="{data.HoofdGroep}" initialize="init(data.HoofdGroep)">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:navigationContent> 
        <s:Button click="navigator.popView()">
            <s:icon>
                 <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource source160dpi="@Embed('assets/arrow_left_24.png')"
                                         source240dpi="@Embed('assets/arrow_left_48.png')"
                                         source320dpi="@Embed('assets/arrow_left_64.png')"/>
            </s:icon>
        </s:Button> 
    </s:navigationContent>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import valueObjects.Dbsql;
            protected function init(HoofdGroep:String):void
            {
                var getClass:Dbsql = new Dbsql();
                list.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(getClass.listGroups(HoofdGroep));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="list" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" labelField="ArtikelSubGroep"> 
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

I just found out that it is important to set the labelField of the list to the name of the column you want to use from the dataProvider. Are there other ways to get the right column from the returned array?

And overall: is this the right approach in Flex Mobile for using packages?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get the list show a different value would be making a custom item renderer for the list.

Inside the custom item renderer you could provide any logic to show the information in the way you want.

for more info read [this link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-performance-checklist.html).

this article will help you not only with the item renderer but with the performance.

now for your second question, do you mean the package namespace?

If is that so, I see that you are creating a 'valueObjects' package and placing a class that doesnt looklike as a valueObject. This class DBsql handles database connection logic, maybe a 'service' name would be better. For example:

com.productName.vo  this would be the root folder for value objects

com.productName.vo.ProductVO (class)

com.productName.vo.ClientVO (class)

the for the model

com.productName.service (folder)

com.productName.service.ProductService (class)

com.productName.service.ClientService (class)

Comment: You left me in the dark here... I know services are used to connect to remote data. This Sqlite db is local (it should be synced in the future with a webservice). I tried to create a object oriented way to do things with data. It works. But when I can do better I will for shure

Comment: sorry for the late response ... It doesnt matter, we currently use the word 'service' as a way to say 'a layer of communication' no matter if it is a local or external entity. It could be a 'service' that communicates with a webservice, a database or a class factory it doesnt matter. Its like when some body says: "I'm at your *service*" 
:)